# How to remove hyperlink of images in wordpress post?

Tags: image, wordpress, hyperlink

This is my first question here.

I need to disable hyperlinks on my images in posts in wordpress cms. I know about "None" button when adding images 2 post but i need some kind of filter cause i cant republish all 199298931092 posts again to make changes.

I tryed to put some code for the_contetn filter in functions.php of my theme but im not so skilled php-er so it was not work. Any suggestions or help. Plz
Best regards
http://www.rofltime.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way to remove those links after you've added them. The links are essentially 'hard-coded' around the images in your post content. I'm afraid you'll have to go through all 199298931092 posts and manually remove the links by clicking 'None' for the link option when editing each image. There are some future-proof methods so this doesn't keep happening, see here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/how-to-remove-link-from-an-image-in-a-post

Comment: Actualy it is... i found solution but im gonna implement it in plugin. Cya soon with dowload link and tutorial

Answer (score 6):

If you want ALL images inside the content :

```
function k99_attachment_image_link_void( $content ) {
    $content =
        preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*><img}','{/></a>}'), array('<img','/>'), $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'k99_attachment_image_link_void' );
```

if you want only attachments inside he content :

```
function k99_image_link_void( $content ) {
    $content =
        preg_replace(
            array('{<a(.*?)(wp-att|wp-content\/uploads)[^>]*><img}',
                '{ wp-image-[0-9]*" /></a>}'),
            array('<img','" />'),
            $content
        );
    return $content;
}


    add_filter( 'the_content', 'k99_image_link_void' );
```